# System.Format.FormatException when trying double.Parse()

Tags: c#, string, parsing, type-conversion, double

My program throws a `System.FormatException: "The entrystring has the wrong format."` whenever I am trying run this code:

```
public double[] ReturnCoordsFromString(string CoordString)
    {
        string[] cArrStr = CoordString.Split(' ');

        List<double> NumList = new List<double>();

        foreach (string elem in cArrStr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(elem);   // <= Error is here
            NumList.Add(b);
        }
        double[] retN = NumList.ToArray<double>();

        return retN;
    }
```

I have also tried to run it with `Convert.ToDouble(elem)` and Encodings with ascii and utf_8. None of these worked.

To understand my code:

I call the function from another function and the `CoordString` argument looks like this:
`90 10 1000`
So they are all Integers, but I need them as double. (I tried `Int32.Parse()` and then convert to double, here it crashes on the `Int32.Parse()` part)

My code should get the CoordString (`"90 10 1000"`) and split it into single strings (`["90", "10", "1000"]`).
The `Console.WriteLine(elem)` prints the correct numbers, no letters, just numbers as string.

Any idea why / how to fix it? Nothing other questions suggested worked so far.

EDIT:

The weird thing is, printing `elem` does work well.  But the Exception Window shows me this:

```
b        0         double
elem     ""        string
// The class name here
```

Comment: what is the value of elem??

Comment: elem is always each individual string from the array from `CoordString.Split(' ')`. Which is always the numbers as string, so first its `90`, then `10`, then `1000`

Comment: I just try your code and it works pretty well. Do you sure that input string looks like this `"90 10 1000"`?

Comment: [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://ideone.com/eVSrVC) throws that Exception when you feed it an empty string which you obviously do. What is `CoordString` when that exception is thrown.

Comment: Printing every variable, it gives me this:
`0 0 200  // This is CoordString`
`0            // First Element`
`0            // Second Element`
`200        // Last element`

Comment: @rene CoordSring doesnt change a single time. It just loops over an array containing numbers as string as elements. And at some point is crashes.

Comment: @JH_WK.Please check Null or Empty value before converting to double.it will be much safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a double space somewhere that's causing the problem. Try specifying `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] cArrStr = CoordString(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

instead of

```
string[] cArrStr = CoordString.Split(' ');
```

Also, you should use `Double.TryParse` and not `Convert.ToDouble`, since `Double.TryParse` will only return false when it can't convert, while `Convert.ToDouble` will throw an exception:

So use this:

```
double b;
if(Double.TryParse(elem, out d))
{
    // value is a double
}
```

instead of

```
double b = Convert.ToDouble(elem);
```